# How can I use val of "contenteditable 1" to update "contenteditable 2" with "keyup" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I am struggling to achieve a solution to my problem:

```
<div id="editable-content">
<span id="static1" class="non-editable">1-800-</span>
<span class="edittext" id="block1" class="editable" placeholder="HELLO" contenteditable="true"autofocus></span>
```

```
<div id="editable-content">
<span id="static2" class="non-editable">1-800-</span>
<span class="edittext" id="block2" class="editable" placeholder="HELLO" contenteditable="true"autofocus></span>
```

I want to use the value of **#block1** to update **#block2** on a keyup event.
Means: As soon as user types into **#block1** the same text simultaneously appears in **#block2**.

This my JS so far but it doesn't do what i want it to do:

```
$( function() {
function updateTextarea() {
    $( '#block2' ).val( $( '#block1' ).val());
}
$( '#block1' ).keyup( updateTextarea );
```

});

What do I do wrong? Thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line:

```
$( '#block2' ).text( $( '#block1' ).text());
```

---

Only form elements does have the value attribute so that can be get via `.value` from javascript or `.val()` method of jQuery.

Although `contenteditable` attribute lets you enter text in the element but that is just textContent of that element not value.

Comment: Thank you! That is what i needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this its a sample code hope this will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="ch1" value="" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="ch2" value="" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ch1").keyup(function(){
        var test = $("#ch1").val();
        $("#ch2").val(test);
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```